# SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'test1' through in hive

Tags: hive, spagobi

1. I am fetaching data from hive2 in SpagoBI 5.1 open source tool.
2. When i am creating dashboard, it shows an error:- Impossible to load dataset [test_connection] due to the following service errors: Method not supported;
3. And, in hive back ground, terminal Shows an error i.e., SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'test1' through in hive.
4. In hive command, hive --service hiveserver2 10000 &.

Thanks

Comment: Need more information. Post your `hive command`, `hive logs`, `hive and hadoop config files`.

Comment: Can be closed as having no [mcve].